# Showing an analytic function takes certain values exactly once

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $D$ be the open unit disk in the complex plane, and let $f(z)$ be a map from $D$ to $D$ with $f(0)=0$. Denoting $|f'(0)|=\delta$, we further require $\delta>0$. Fix $\eta>0$ with $\eta<\delta$. I have shown that for $z$ with $|z|<\eta$, we have

$$|f(z)|\ge \left( \frac{\delta -\eta}{1+\eta\delta}\right)|z|.$$

I want to show that in the disk $|z|<\eta$, $f(z)$ takes on each value $w$ in the following disk once:

$$|w|< \left( \frac{\delta -\eta}{1+\eta\delta}\right)\eta.$$

I thought about using Rouché's theorem, but did not see how to apply it. How does one show this?

If it helps, I think it is possible the inequality I have shown is strict, but I will need to re-check some details. For the proof, apply the Schwarz-Pick lemma to $f(z)/z$ with the points $z$ and $0$ (so $|z|$ is the upper bound, and $f(z)/z$ at zero becomes $f'(0)$), then set $w$ equal to the left-hand side of the inequality, solve for $f(z)/z$ in terms of $w$, and use the triangle inequality to make the obvious bounds. I can provide more details if needed.

There's also the possibility of a typo. The book I am working from is riddled with errors, and I believe I even spotted an error in the errata for this problem (the correct version, as far as I can tell, is the way I stated it above). If you suspect there is a mistake with the problem statement, please let me know. For reference, the version in the errata is as above, but with the constant in both inequalities replaced by

$$\left( \frac{\delta -\eta}{1-\eta\delta}\right).$$

Note the sign change. To reiterate, I think the version stated above is correct, and that the errata is in error.

This is an exercise on page $39$ of Garnett's *Bounded Analytic Functions*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The inequality is right as you have it. I believe $\dfrac{\delta+\eta}{1-\delta\eta}$ gives the coefficient for an *upper* bound. Yes, you're right to use Rouché. If $|f(z)|\ge C$ on $|z|=\eta$ and $|w|<C$ then $g(z)=f(z)-w$ has the same number of roots in $|z|<\eta$ as $f$, i.e., one.

Comment: Of course! I was being silly when I tried to apply Rouché. Thank you.